# WPF Customcontrol, Templates, Inheritance and Dependencyproperties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got some troubles with a custom control I need to create. I try to explain you my needs first

I need to have a combobox that permits to check more than one item at time (with checkbox) but I want it to be smart enought to bind to a specific type.

I've found some MultiSelectionComboBox but none reflects my need.
Btw my main problem is that I wish to have a generic class as

```
public class BaseClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<T>), typeof(BaseClass<T>), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
 new PropertyChangedCallback(BaseClass<T>.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //MultiSelectComboBox control = (MultiSelectComboBox)d;
        //control.DisplayInControl();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<T>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public class BaseClass : Control
{

}
```

and a more context specific item for example

```
public class MultiCurr : BaseClass<Currency>
{
    static MultiCurr()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiCurr), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MultiCurr)));
    }
}
```

In my App.xaml I've defined a resource as

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="local:MultiCurr">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MultiCurr">
                        <ComboBox Width="120" Background="Red" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" ></ComboBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

In my MainWindow I've created an object as

```
<Grid>
    <local:MultiCurr x:Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding Currencies}"></local:MultiCurr>
</Grid>
```

and the MainWindow.cs is defined as

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private IList currencies;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lst = new List<Currency>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var curr = new Currency
            {
                ID = i,
                Description = string.Format("Currency_{0}", i)
            };

            lst.Add(curr);
        }

        Currencies = lst;
    }
    public IList<Currency> Currencies
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currencies;
        }
        set
        {
            this.currencies = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Currencies");

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the result ... 
[image: The result is this one]

I was wondering what am I doing wrong? is it possible what am I tring to achieve?

Thanks

**UPDATE #1:**

I've seen that the main problem is the datacontext of the custom usercontrol

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="local:MultiCurr">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MultiCurr">
                        <ComboBox Width="120" Background="Red" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding **Currencies**}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding **DisplayMemeberPath**}" ></ComboBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If I put ItemsSource as Currency (which is a property of the MainWindow) it shows.
If I put ItemsSource and DisplayMemberPath (which are defined in the BaseClass no.. how can I set the context of the usercontrol to itself?)

**UPDATE #2**
I've added a GoogleDrive link to the project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6nPFuIuKHG1dE1PazFHdGg4NHc/view?usp=sharing) if anyone wants to try the solution

Thanks

Comment: In your controltemplate use template binding iso binding.

Comment: is `currencies` an `ObservableCollection`? And by the way, you shouldn't have setters for your lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Combobox is not suitable control** for multiselection, because it has given behaviour, that when yo select item, Combobox closes itself. That's why Combobox doest not have SelectionMode property like ListBox. I think that **ListBox inside expander is what you need**.
2. Generic Types are not a way to go. WPF handles this different, better way. Take listbox as an example. If you bind listbox.itemssource to generic observable collection, and you try to define e.g ItemTemplate, you get full intellisense when writing bindings and warning if you bind to not existing property. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/03/01/~/media/ECG/visualstudiomagazine/Images/2014/03/Figure8.ashx WPF designer automatically recognizes type parameter of your observable collection. Of cousre you need to specify type of datacontext in your page by using something like this: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance search:AdvancedSearchPageViewModel}"`. However your control dont have to be and **shouldn't be aware of type of items**.

Following example demonstrates control that meets your requirements:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=PART_ListBox, Path=SelectedItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Run Text=";" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.Content>
        <ListBox x:Name="PART_ListBox" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="system:String">
                    <system:String>ABC</system:String>
                    <system:String>DEF</system:String>
                    <system:String>GHI</system:String>
                    <system:String>JKL</system:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        </ListBox>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

I reccomend you to create control derived from ListBox (not usercontrol).
I have hardcoded datatemplates, but you should expose them in your custom dependency properties and use TemplateBinding in you control template. Of course you need to modify expander so it looks like combobox and ListBoxItem style so it looks like CheckBox, but it is ease.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in my case I'm 90% at work... combobox works fine I just have some troubles with passing the ItemsSource from the mainview to the usercontrol...btw I'll take a look thanks

Comment: You need to create ItemsSource dependecyproperty in your UserControl. And databind your combobox or whatever like this: <Combobox ItemsSource="`{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`"

Comment: Liero if you look at my code above I've a combobox defined in the style,I've just created the property in the BaseClass<T> from which the MultiCurr inherits from .. if in my App's resource I specify Currencies as itemsource (which is the property of the MainWindow it work) , if I specify ItemsSource not

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned UserControl in you comment. that confused me. You just need to replace all Bindings with `TemplateBinding` in your control template.